# THREE.js SphereGeometry Panorama hotspots using DOMElements

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

I've created a simple WebGL 3D Panorama application using a `SphereGeometry`, `PerspectiveCamera` and a `CanvasTexture`. Now, I'm looking to bring the scene to life by adding "HotSpots" over certain parts of the `SphereGeometry`. The problem I'm having is understanding how to update the various `DOMElements` so that their position is reflective of the updated `Camera` position.

Basically, as the `Camera` rotates the various `DOMElements` would move in and out of view relative to the direction the camera is spinning. I tried positioning a `<div>` `absolute` to the `<canvas>` and `translating` the `X` and `Y` position using the returned `PerspectiveCamera` `camera.rotation` but it didn't really work; here's my JS & CSS implentation:

**CSS**

```
#TestHotSpot {
    /* not sure if using margins is the best method to position hotspot */
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
/** 
   CONFIG is my stored object variable; it contains the PerspectiveCamera instance 
   code is being called inside of my RequestAnimationFrame
**/

config.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
config.controls.update(delta);

document.getElementById("TestHotSpot").style.transform = "translate("+ config.camera.rotation.x +"px, "+ config.camera.rotation.y +"px)";
```

[Here](http://mpetroff.net/software/pannellum/) is also a live example of the desired effect.

What would be the best solution to fix this problem? What I noticed when I ran this that the `DOMElements` would only slightly move; I also noticed that they wouldn't really take in account where along the `SphereGeometry` they were placed (for example, being positioned "behind" the `Camera`; really complex!

I'm happy to use any plugins for the `THREE.js` engine as well as follow any tutorials. Thank you so much for replying in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Try to set a planemesh/mesh to the desired point.
2. Copy the position of the css elements (domElements created with three.js cssObject [if you already know]) along with planemesh/mesh 's position.

And you will be done !!

Comment: Hi @serious_s, thanks so much for your reply! I tried finding some docs on how to these the `cssObject` but turned up empty handed. Do you have a code snippet example that explains how to use it? I'm still a little bit confused - sorry!

Comment: Hi again! After doing some more research, I understand your answer now - thanks for your help! Upvoted.

Comment: If you don't mind please do share your research, what tuts or reading did you do, what else did you find, do you have a few good links that would perhaps also enable me to understand this whole process. Thank you for any related info that you could be asked to share.

Comment: hi @lindsay thanks for the upvote. I din't notice your comment since I'm still a noob in stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Okay, chiming in on my own question! I had a few problems but I've figured out how to get CSS3d mixing in with THREE.js WebGL scenes.

So the first thing I had to do was update my THREE.js Library; I was running 71 from an earlier download but I needed to update it to the library Mr.Doob was using in [**this**](http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_sandbox.html) example. I also updated my CSS3d library to the file included in that same example.

I then used this method (the same specified in the link) to create a demo scene.

```
var camera, scene, renderer;

var scene2, renderer2;

var controls;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
    camera.position.set( 200, 200, 200 );

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene2 = new THREE.Scene();

    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 1, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );

            //

    for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i ++ ) {

        var element = document.createElement( 'div' );
            element.style.width = '100px';
            element.style.height = '100px';
            element.style.opacity = 0.5;
            element.style.background = new THREE.Color( Math.random() * 0xffffff ).getStyle();

        var object = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
            object.position.x = Math.random() * 200 - 100;
            object.position.y = Math.random() * 200 - 100;
            object.position.z = Math.random() * 200 - 100;
            object.rotation.x = Math.random();
            object.rotation.y = Math.random();
            object.rotation.z = Math.random();
            object.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
            object.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
        scene2.add( object );

        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100 );
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.position.copy( object.position );
            mesh.rotation.copy( object.rotation );
            mesh.scale.copy( object.scale );
        scene.add( mesh );

    }

            //

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    renderer2 = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    renderer2.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer2.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    renderer2.domElement.style.top = 0;
    document.body.appendChild( renderer2.domElement );

}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    controls.update();

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    renderer2.render( scene2, camera );

}
```

After I had that working, I re-purposed the `CSS3d scene`, `CSS3d object` and the `CSS3d renderer` to be included in my scene.

Good luck to anyone else and hopefully this helps!

Comment: I am also trying to add hotspots with links to other panoramas. Would you mind sharing more of how you accomplished this? Perhaps you could make a jsfiddle please? I am a brutal beginner with ThreeJS and posted this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148586/place-link-or-hotspot-inside-equirectangular-panorama-with-three-js and am still looking for good examples or tutorials to help me better understand the whole matter. Would be eternally happy to understand and code this myself. If you can be asked to make a quick jsfiddle that would be super great!

Comment: 2021 - This was still relevant for helping get clickable elements to overlay my `SphereGeometry` so the element pans with the rest of the panorama. Just a couple of tweaks: `import { CSS3DRenderer, CSS3DObject } from './assets/js/CSS3DRenderer.js';`, `renderer2 = new CSS3DRenderer();`